# overlappnig 2 images in webforms

Tags: image, visual-studio-2012, webforms, overlapping

I want to show 2 images in same position (overlapping 2 pictures) by visual studio 2012 in Asp.net web forms but I can't & I could not find anything in my searchs
can some one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the answer ...
I should use (for example) "margin-left" or "margin-bottom" in image style;
like the follow code : 
`<img src="Images/MapRD.jpg" /><img height="35" width="30" src="Images/PersonIcon.png" style="margin-left: -250px; margin-bottom: +100px;" />`